# Twitter4j's ConfigureBuilder Class cannot be found

Tags: java, twitter4j

So I've been trying to play around with Twitter4j and I got everything up till the point where I could compile everything. But there was an error that said "java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set."

I read in a few places that I needed the ConfigureBuilder class below. However, whenever I try to compile it the compiler says it cannot find ConfigureBuilder. I have redownloaded the Twitter4j files 3 times already.

The IDE I use is BlueJ if that might help.

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TwitterTyper4j {

static String consumerKeyStr = "";
static String consumerSecretStr = "";
static String accessTokenStr = "";
static String accessTokenSecretStr = "";


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        //twitter confic
       ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
      builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
      builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
      Configuration configuration = builder.build();


      TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
      Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

      twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
      AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(accessTokenStr,
                accessTokenSecretStr);

      twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);

      twitter.updateStatus("Hello Twitter");

      System.out.println("Successfully updated the status in       Twitter.");
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        te.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where is `cb` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have a recent version `twitter-core-x.y.z.jar` on the classpath – I'm sure you do already, but it's worth a check.

Then you need to import the `ConfigurationBuilder`, e.g.:

```
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
```

That should, hopefully, resolve *that* compilation error. Although there are other problems in the code which you will need to fix – where is `cb` declared for example?

**EDIT:**

This is a bit speculative but assuming there's a typo and that `cb` and `configuration` could be the same...

You have already given the consumer secret and key to the builder which was then used to construct the `Twitter` instance.

Then on the `Twitter` instance, which is already configured with the key and secret, you set it again:

```
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
```

Note that the Javadocs for that method state:

> @throws `IllegalStateException` when OAuth consumer has already been set, or the instance is using basic authorization